# How to create simple contact form?

Tags: html

I found this example on w3schools and change email to my email, but when I click Send nothing happens. Where is the problem?

```
<h3>Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h3>

<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Tip #1: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: Do you have an email client installed?  The `MAILTO:` action directs the browser to use the default email client.

Comment: [Try this link instead](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CE0QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.quackit.com%2Fhtml%2Fcodes%2Fhtml_form_to_email.cfm&ei=_po3UZXlMoTd2QXkp4HoDw&usg=AFQjCNEJacfGiWuAfP3G3zVQLL-VJLzA0A&bvm=bv.43287494,d.b2I)

Comment: @Adel: That assumes he's using PHP.  I see no indication of that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. It is unreliable as it depends on the mail client the user has installed and you can not test for that.

instead you should either post the form data to a php script that uses the

php mail() function - which is easy to learn

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = $_POST['comment'];
$headers = 'From:'. $_POST['email']. "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

or use a cgi script like

http://www.response-o-matic.com/

Comment: Or any number of server-side components that would send email.  Whatever the OP has available and is comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really sending the email when you use the mailto:someone@example.org All you're doing is telling the browser that it should handle what follows as an email address and so, the browser will open the default mail client.

The only way to send an email programmatically, which I think is what you are trying to do, is to use a server side script. Something like PHP or ASP.NET to just give two examples.